# Вывод изображение в WebView

Tags: android, webview

Не удается выводить изображение через файл `raw/n0.html` на `WebView`. Использую код `<img src="image.jpg">`, но не пооучается. Картинка находится в папке `raw`. Или для этого нужно написать какой-то код в `ViewActivity`. Если да, то объясните.

Код `ViewActivity`, в котором находится `WebView`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //скрываем заголовок

    setContentView(R.layout.view);


    //скрываем строку состояния

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса

    Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

    //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.akmaltilloev.frameeditguide"));

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
    myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8"); //загружаем текст в webview

}

public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) //читаем текст из raw
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Comment: почему нельзя использовать ImageView?

Comment: На компьютере в браузере Ваш `n0.html` правильно отображается? Попробуйте сделать build->clean project. Если не поможет добавьте в вопрос Ваш код загрузки страницы в `WebView`

Comment: Andriy Martsinkevych, у меня идёт чтение файлов из папки `raw` и тексты из этих файлов выводится на `WebView` и я хочу чтобы картинка выводилась между текстом и в `WebView`

Comment: woesss, Изображение в браузере хорошо отображается. Пока что под рукой нет компьютера не могу сказать о результатах `build>clean project` Добавил код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Страница загруженная таким образом не имеет адреса и так как изображению задан относительный путь, то неизвестно где его искать.
Вам нужно использовать метод с указанием базового адреса для страницы:

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/",
             summary, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: Изменить `loadData` который у меня есть с этим?

Comment: Да. Так Вы скажете `WebView`, что страница лежит в ресурсах в папке `raw`

Comment: Если выдаёт ошибку, то будьте добры писать какую

Comment: А как включить​ масштабирование?

Comment: Ну а [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) на что? `myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`